# Programs for printing reverse triangle patterns with * in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to explore Scala. I am new to Scala. This might be a simple question and searched in google to get below scenario to solve. But couldn't get answers. Instead of Scala I am getting Java related things.
My requirement to print format like below.

```
* * * * * 
 * * * *
  * * *
    *
```

Can someone suggest me how to get this format.

Thanks in advance.

Kanti

Comment: Hi @Kanti, what have you tried? What problems did you have? Do you have an algorithm in mind? You said you only find **Java** things, well you can mostly do the same in **Scala**, just change the syntax a little bit - unless you want to go on a more _functional_ style _(rather than imperative)_, but if that is the objective, you should put that on the question.

Comment: What have you already? What encountered error?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to start these kind of scenarios. I am learning things. I am expecting someone to help this kind of programs

Comment: @kanti Start defining the function signature, think what should it do for its input, when should it stop. Also think step by step, how you should manage each line. Try to solve the problem by hand on a whiteboard, as mechanical as you can, that will be the algorithm, once you have it, you can put it in code.

Comment: I guess Luis is right. You might just start by setting up your Scala project and understand how to write your main function that does the usual Hello World! print. It'd be kind of useless if people do that exercise here for you, don't you think? Start here https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions

Comment: To do this kind of problem, you need to have an idea of how you would go about solving it - how do you work out how many start to print on each row? How do you work out how many spaces before the first star and between subsequent stars? Stuff like that. Once you've got a rough idea, then you should start trying to implement it. If I gave you a solution in JavaScript, and you understood why I did each bit, then you could probably port it over into what language you liked yourself. Without understanding the problem though, you're basically stuck (regardless of language).

Comment: In terms of implementing this, it's just a case of "how do I print stuff to the terminal?", "how do I work out how many stars/spaces I need for each row?" - it's just basic maths at that point, unless you want to make your solution overly complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of illustration, here are two possible solution to the problem.
The first one is completely **imperative**, while the second one is more **functional**.

The idea is that this serves as an example to help you think how to solve problems in a programmatic way.
As many of us have already commented, if you do not understand the basic ideas behind the solution, then this code will be useless in the long term.

Here is the imperative solution, the idea is simple, we need to print `n` lines, each line contains `n - i` starts *(where `i` is the number of the line, starting at `0`)*. The starts are separated by an empty space.
Finally, before printing the starts, we need some padding, looking at example inputs, you can see that the padding starts at `0` and increases by `1` for each line.

```
def printReverseTriangle(n: Int): Unit = {
  var i = 0
  var padding = 0
  while (i < n) {
    var j = padding
    while (j > 0) {
      print(" ")
      j -= 1
    }

    var k = n - i
    while (k > 0) {
      print("* ")
      k -= 1
    }

    println()
    i += 1
    padding += 1
  }
}
```

And here is a more functional approach.
As you can see, in this case we do not need to mutate anything, all the high level operators do that for us. And we only need to focus on the description of the solution.

```
def printReverseTriangle(size: Int): Unit = {
  def makeReverseTriangle(size: Int): List[String] =
    List.tabulate(size) { i =>
      (" " * (size - i)) + ("* " * i)
    }.reverse

  println(makeReverseTriangle(size).mkString("\n"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luis. It really helps me.

Comment: could you tell me what is down vote. I am not sure what is down vote

Comment: @kanti A down vote, or a negative vote is when someone clicks the arrow that is down the score. And it is used to signal that the question or answer is not useful, or is bad, or things like that. Is like a dislike. You can click the score itself a see that it has 1 vote and 1 down vote, thus the total score is `1 - 1 = 0` -  I am asking _(to whoever did)_ why this answer deserves such down vote.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer starts with an imperative solution which I don't think is useful, especially for someone just starting with Scala.

Answer (score 1):

To add an alternative to Luis's answer, here's a recursive solution:

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def printStars(i: Int): Unit = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(j: Int): Unit = {
    if(j > 0) {
      val stars = Range(0, j).map(_ => "*").mkString(" ") // make stars
      if(i == j) println(stars)                           // no need for spaces
      else println((" " * (i - j)) + stars)               // spaces before the stars
      loop(j - 1)
    }
  }
  loop(i)
}

printStars(3)
// * * *
//  * *
//   *
```

This function will take a maximum triangle size (`i`), and for that size until `i` is no longer greater than 0 it will print out the correct number of stars (and spaces), then decrement by 1.

Note: `Range(0, j).map(_ => "*").mkString(" ")` can be replaced with `List.tabulate(j)(_ => "*").mkString(" ")` per Luis's answer - I'm not sure which is faster (I've not tested it).

Comment: They should be equivalent in performance, in any case if one really care about performance, the best would be a `while`+  a **StringBuilder** _(with the correct initial capacity)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez either way I think the bottleneck in this function will be actually printing to the terminal, not the way you generate the stars... no matter how quick your star generator is, it'll still take forever to print out 1000000 stars.

Comment: probably yes, but precisely using a **StringBuilder** would help in that, since it is better to do few but big prints that many but small.